# Can I have different plugins loaded for different projects in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am actually deactivating some plugins for my IntelliJ project. Some of them I see still useful in other IntelliJ projects. I figured out I had to reactivate them when I switch to those projects. That is pretty inconvenient.

Is there a way to have different plugin setups for different projects?

Comment: No, there is no such feature as of IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Required Plugins` feature, see [Managing required plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#managing-required-plugins) section of the documentation:

> **Managing required plugins**
>
> When working on a project, you can install plugins that provide
>   support for a certain technology or a framework. If necessary, you can
>   add such plugins to the list of required plugins for the current
>   project. IntelliJ IDEA in this case will ensure that the plugins that
>   are necessary for your project to work are available.
>
> To manage required plugins
>
> 1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog (⌘,),
>      click Required Plugins under Build, Execution, Deployment.
> 2. On the
>      Required Plugins page, use the  Add,  Remove, and  Edit buttons to
>      manage the list of required plugins. To add a required plugin, click 
>      Add and provide the name of the plugin in the dialog that opens.
>      Optionally, provide the required minimum and maximum plugin versions
>      and the preferred update channel.

Comment: This feature indeed exists, but it doesn't allow to use a different set of plugins for different projects. All it does is check that you have a plugin installed when you open the project. If you do install the plugin, it will be applied to all projects.